# Parse error when trying to remove time and change date format?

Tags: python, pandas, date, parsing, time

I am trying to remove time and change format of my dates in my social media dataset so it is compatible with my stock data when I merge both datasets.

This my social media dataset sample:

```
0       id      created_at
1       1       7:51 PM ET Fri, 17 July 2020
2       2       7:33 PM ET Fri, 17 July 2020
4       4       7:25 PM ET Fri, 17 July 2020
5       5       4:24 PM ET Fri, 17 July 2020
…       …       …
3076    3076    10:15 AM ET Tue, 26 Dec 2017
3077    3077    11:12 AM ET Thu, 20 Sept 2018
3078    3078    7:07 PM ET Fri, 22 Dec 2017
3079    3079    7:07 PM ET Fri, 22 Dec 2017
3080    3080    6:52 PM ET Fri, 22 Dec 2017
```

I am trying to get the date to look like this:

```
Date        Open    High
2017-12-22  2684.22 2685.35
2017-12-26  2679.09 2682.74
2017-12-27  2682.10 2685.64
2017-12-28  2686.10 2687.66
2017-12-29  2689.15 2692.12
```

This is what I have tried but it hasn't worked:

```
pd.to_datetime(data['created_at'])
```

But I get error:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimes.py in objects_to_datetime64ns(data, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, errors, require_iso8601, allow_object)
   2053         try:
-> 2054             values, tz_parsed = conversion.datetime_to_datetime64(data)
   2055             # If tzaware, these values represent unix timestamps, so we

pandas/_libs/tslibs/conversion.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.datetime_to_datetime64()

TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-34e0ddb54ab0> in <module>
----> 1 pd.to_datetime(data['created_at'])

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py in to_datetime(arg, errors, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, format, exact, unit, infer_datetime_format, origin, cache)
    801             result = arg.map(cache_array)
    802         else:
--> 803             values = convert_listlike(arg._values, format)
    804             result = arg._constructor(values, index=arg.index, name=arg.name)
    805     elif isinstance(arg, (ABCDataFrame, abc.MutableMapping)):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py in _convert_listlike_datetimes(arg, format, name, tz, unit, errors, infer_datetime_format, dayfirst, yearfirst, exact)
    457         assert format is None or infer_datetime_format
    458         utc = tz == "utc"
--> 459         result, tz_parsed = objects_to_datetime64ns(
    460             arg,
    461             dayfirst=dayfirst,

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimes.py in objects_to_datetime64ns(data, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, errors, require_iso8601, allow_object)
   2057             return values.view("i8"), tz_parsed
   2058         except (ValueError, TypeError):
-> 2059             raise e
   2060 
   2061     if tz_parsed is not None:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimes.py in objects_to_datetime64ns(data, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, errors, require_iso8601, allow_object)
   2042 
   2043     try:
-> 2044         result, tz_parsed = tslib.array_to_datetime(
   2045             data,
   2046             errors=errors,

pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime()

pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime()

pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime_object()

pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime_object()

pandas/_libs/tslibs/parsing.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.parsing.parse_datetime_string()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dateutil/parser/_parser.py in parse(timestr, parserinfo, **kwargs)
   1366         return parser(parserinfo).parse(timestr, **kwargs)
   1367     else:
-> 1368         return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
   1369 
   1370 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dateutil/parser/_parser.py in parse(self, timestr, default, ignoretz, tzinfos, **kwargs)
    641 
    642         if res is None:
--> 643             raise ParserError("Unknown string format: %s", timestr)
    644 
    645         if len(res) == 0:

ParserError: Unknown string format: created_at
```

Thank you for the help :)

Edit: [Sample of dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NgYK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split on `,`  and keep the second part (the date) and convert it to a datetime with `pd.to_datetime`:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'].str.split(', ').str[1])
1      2020-07-17
2      2020-07-17
4      2020-07-17
5      2020-07-17
3076   2017-12-26
3077   2018-09-20
3078   2017-12-22
3079   2017-12-22
3080   2017-12-22
Name: created_at, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

---

**Old answer**
You can use `dateutil` package (already installed with `pandas`):

```
from dateutil import parser

>>> df['created_at'].apply(parser.parse, tzinfos={'ET': -4*3600})

1      2020-07-17 19:51:00-04:00
2      2020-07-17 19:33:00-04:00
4      2020-07-17 19:25:00-04:00
5      2020-07-17 16:24:00-04:00
3076   2017-12-26 10:15:00-04:00
3077   2018-09-20 11:12:00-04:00
3078   2017-12-22 19:07:00-04:00
3079   2017-12-22 19:07:00-04:00
3080   2017-12-22 18:52:00-04:00
Name: created_at, dtype: datetime64[ns, tzoffset('ET', -14400)]
```

You can add another timezones to the dict `tzinfos` if needeed.

**Update**

> ParserError: Unknown string format: created_at.

This exception is raised because in the column `df['created_at']`, you have a value which is 'created_at'. For instance:

```
>>> df
   id                    created_at
0   0                         hello  # <- it's not a valid datetime
1   1  7:51 PM ET Fri, 17 July 2020
2   2  7:33 PM ET Fri, 17 July 2020

>>> df['created_at'].apply(parser.parse, tzinfos={'ET': -4*3600})

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)

...

ParserError: Unknown string format: hello  # 'hello' is not a valid datetime
```

To find incorrect, search all rows that not contain 'AM' or 'PM' as value:

```
>>> df.loc[~df['created_at'].str.contains(r'(?:AM|PM)'), 'created_at']

1    hello
Name: created_at, dtype: object
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. But I get error NameError: name 'parser' is not defined when applying your code. Any ideas?

Comment: @user16561849. Don't forget to import module like this: `from dateutil import parser`.

Comment: Ah sorry silly mistake. However, it still says ParserError: Unknown string format: created_at.

Comment: You have a value in `df['created_at']` which is 'created_at' so the parser can't decode this string as a valid date format.

Comment: So to solve this I need to change 'created_at' to 'Date'?

Comment: Ahh I see so within my column 'created_at' I have a value. How would I identify and remove this value? Thank you so much for the help, it has been very informative

Comment: It seems to have listed everything? Maybe there is an error within the dataset itself. It may be best to manually remove time and change format in excel

Comment: I don't understand why. Your sample is right, isn't it? Don't forget the `~`

Comment: I have included a sample from jupyter notebook of my dataset. That would be brilliant how do I share my excel file? Thanks so much for this

Comment: This is your first row!!! Drop it. `df = df.iloc[1:]` and retry. I don't know why your first row is the same as column index.

Comment: Ohh of course! I ran the code and it is now working but it has not removed the time or formated the date into YR/MON/DAY. I tried using data.loc[:, 'created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(data['created_at'],format='%Y-%m-%d') but it has not worked.

Comment: You have been most helpful, thank you :) Has this removed time entirely or just changed it to 00:00:00?